# How do I set my smart-contract / account to "immutable"?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, permissions, immutability

What's the correct cleos command to yield the active/owner permissions of a deployed contract to "eosio.code", exclusively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cleos set account permission MYACCOUNT active '{"threshold": 1, "keys":[], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"eosio.null","permission":"active"},"permission":{"actor":"MYACCOUNT","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[] }' owner -p MYACCOUNT
cleos set account permission MYACCOUNT owner '{"threshold": 1, "keys":[], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"eosio.null","permission":"owner"},"permission":{"actor":"MYACCOUNT","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[] }' -p MYACCOUNT@owner
```

Some additional points:

1. The permissions *must* be given in alphabetical order (of account name), so I am assuming that your account name would come alphabetically after `eosio.null`. If that isn't true, then you have to rearrange the permissions such that it is alphabetically correct.
2. Be aware, that the `eosio.code` permission can be used to authorise any action that the permission could normally achieve. This means that it can be used to change the keys within the contract itself. Assuming the point of nulling the keys is to make the contract immutable and provide confidence in the contract, then you will have to make it open source so that people can see that you haven't snuck a function in there that will be called at some point and change the keys so you can regain access.

Comment: I'm getting the following error, using the first line (replacing "MYACCOUNT" for "wubiubitoken"):
Error 3010004: Invalid authority
Ensure that your authority JSON is valid follows the following format!
(...)
Error Details:
Fail to parse Authority JSON '{"threshold": 1, "keys":[], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"eosio.null","permission":"active"},{"permission":{"actor":"wubiubitoken","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[] }'
Expected '"' but read '{'
while parsing token ''
Error parsing object
Attempting to parse array []
Error parsing object

Comment: I think I solved the parse error (an extra "{"), but the second command now gives the following error (which says "active" but I'm setting the owner): Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"wubiubitoken","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.

Comment: I changed the end of the second command to " -p wubiubitoken@owner " and it went through.

Comment: oops my mistake. By all means edit the answer as appropriate. Where is the extra `{`?

Comment: It's in the second "permission" statement. It should be ,"  instead of ,{"   Stackoverflow doesn't let me edit it because it's less than 6 characters

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but as far as I can see the first permission statement and the second one look identical (apart from the active/owner differences). Can you maybe write the command how you think it should look like here in a comment then I will be able to edit it myself

Comment: Here are the two commands with the offending "{" removed. The confusion may be on my end -- cleos set account permission MYACCOUNT active '{"threshold": 1, "keys":[], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"eosio.null","permission":"active"},"permission":{"actor":"MYACCOUNT","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[] }' owner -p MYACCOUNT
cleos set account permission MYACCOUNT owner '{"threshold": 1, "keys":[], "accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"eosio.null","permission":"owner"},"permission":{"actor":"MYACCOUNT","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}], "waits":[] }' -p MYACCOUNT@owner